# Is it the font or color scheme that makes this site hard to bear for me?

Tags: discussion, design, fonts

I am generally having a hard time reading many of the questions in this font / color scheme of the new site. Honestly, the new layout and colors make me not want to come back to this site at all. This is actually the third time I have gotten on since it was moved from beta.

I find it very hard to read and the overall theme to be silly to say the lease. I will try to find an actual example of where I find it especially hard to read, but it is not just me. Some people I work with that used to participate on this site no longer do due to the new theme.

Comment: Yes please point to specific things. SE has a designer who can address them if we can take him specific things. However, the overall design stuff was addressed on meta a few months ago and there were plenty of opportunities to comment. Every post was featured in the sidebar on the main site as well as here on the meta site.

Comment: Yea, lunch started with a Baptist, Morman, and Catholic sitting down and lambasting the new site design. Sounds like the beginning of a joke.

Comment: If the ones having problems all work at the same place, the problem may be the monitors.

Comment: Honestly, I think it may just be all the really light colors for everything. I find it kinda hurts my eyes.

Comment: It is possible to use a custom style sheet to override the colors (I've considered changing the yellow/orange/gold(?) for myself); it would be a shame to leave because of the color scheme.

Comment: I agree with Ryan Frame, but such does not seem to be *easy*. It is not clear that non-Mozilla browsers support the equivalent of @moz-document to specify url-specific styling (@document is not yet part of a W3C Recommendation, a.k.a. standard). Changing all the color and background-color entries would also be a bit tedious if one is particular about excellence. I am too style-challenged to do a good job or care much. Perhaps someone can provide an alternative stylesheet?

Comment: The main site, meta or both? I find meta weird but the main alright.

Comment: I have just visited this site for the first time and it hurts my eyes. I would suppose this is because of the sans font used, which is usually used only in books (or paper) and it hurts eyes in low sizes. That's why web typography usually prefers sans-serif fonts :(

Comment: @Sulthan: The font used in this site is serif not sans. For long passages with relatively small size, reading on screen extremely hurts our eyes (nerves contracted, fatigue, dizzy, etc).