# The font used in this site is not good for on screen reading

Tags: discussion, design, fonts

It  is hard to read on screen with the current serif font. Please kindly consider to change to sans serif fonts such as Arial, Droid Sans, Georgia, etc.

Serif fonts are only good for printing.

Comment: Ask some experts from tex.stackexchange.com how to choose better font for on-screen reading. They are qualified typographers.

Comment: [We are switching to system fonts on May 10, 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021?cb=1).

Comment: Related: [Is it the font or color scheme that makes this site hard to bear for me?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1835/is-it-the-font-or-color-scheme-that-makes-this-site-hard-to-bear-for-me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just started using the Dark Reader extension for Firefox, and you can find similar add-on on your browser; it helps in dark mode for any site we want, as well as can change the font too. It works just amazing. You can set specific themes for each website to fix fonts. [image: See]

Answer (score 0):

**The font used in this site is not good for on screen reading?**

As Nigel J pointed out in the comments, we are improving our fonts usages in our systems starting today, May 10, 2021.

[We are switching to system fonts on May 10, 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048/we-are-switching-to-system-fonts-on-may-10-2021?cb=1)

There may be some initial delays amongst some individual sites as well as some unforeseen delays due to bugs, etcetera, so some degree of patience may be required.

Apparently, as of one hour ago this feature went live!

Apparently, Christianity SE will not be changing.

**Sites like Christianity and English will still be displayed in their custom fonts.**

Comment: The custom fonts that are currently in use are serif fonts, unpleasant for on-screen reading.

Comment: @KimJongUn This is out of moderators’ hands and one can only make a complaint to SE management.

Comment: Thanks. Understood.